# Linq how to only return when all meet a condition?

Tags: linq

I want to loop over a list of objects and check a boolean value until all are true then return.

Is this possible with Linq??

In other words:

> List of < obj {1, true}, obj {1, false}, obj {1, false}, obj {1,
>   false}
>   >

but the bool is being updated by something else and I want to check the bool until all are true then return control.

How to do with linq?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a boolean value using `.Any()` to indicate any of the values is false in your collection.

```
while( yourCollection.Any(q => q.BooleanVariable == false)) { }
```

This will run until all of the variables are set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your collection is being updated while you want to continuously check it, you will need to separate the checking logic and logic which updates the list into different threads.

```
AutoResetEvent waitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkitem
(
    work =>
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            if(!yourCollection.Any(x => x.BooleanVariable == false))
            {
                waitEvent.Set();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
);

//alternatively, you could already have another thread running that is updating the list
new Thread(
{
    //do some stuff that updates the list here
}).Start();

waitEvent.WaitOne();

//continue doing stuff when all items in list are true
```